# Google drive API : How to find all files I shared with others

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am using drive api v3 to look for files I hare shared with others (anyone),to list them & potentially cancel sharing them.
I know that in the search box you can do a 'to:' and it will retrieve these files, but I could not use such thing on the API.
my current tri ;

```
query="'me' in owners and trashed=false and not mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and visibility != 'limited'"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, your files that you shared with `anyone` in your Google Drive cannot be directly searched by the search query. So for example, how about this workaround? At first, it retrieves the narrowed file list with your search query. And from the retrieved file list, it confirms whether `"type": "anyone"` is included in the array object of `permissions`. I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want. So I posted this as a comment. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hello, 
thank you for this answer, that's actually exactly what I am doing right now, but it has one down side, speed, since I am operating over drives containing a lot of files, that's why I was hoping by adding 'visibility=limited' I could speed up the process. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) said, a workaround that solves the problem is by looping through the files using files.list() function, and including id, owners, permissions in the fields. This is going to return a list of objects, and from there we can check if `type` is `anyone`.
From there, we can also check for attributes like `shared:true` & `ownedByMe:true`.

This is just a workaround, and surely not the best solution, since with Drive search, we can do all this by typing `to:`, which lists all owr shared files. I hope we get an API for this.

Thanks again [tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)